# Avid juicy three piston popped out when bleeding without block

Tags: brakes

So, First time bleeding juicy three brakes. I bought a cheap bleeding kit, didn't use a bleed block and the piston was pushed out.Feel a little stupid now.

Pushed piston back in and let the excess fluid out but now there is no reaction from the brakes. The lever goes to the bar. Are the brakes useless? They are about five years old avid juicy threes.

Thank you.

Comment: It may be that there is a lot of air in the lines, at very least they will need a proper re-bleeding. That would be my first reaction, but i have never popped a piston out, if there is a seal involved with the piston it may be that it got pushed out of position as well and is not allowing a proper seal to be made.

Comment: Might be worth doing a complete fluid flush instead of a simple bleed.

Comment: I did this once, was fine after a full bleed. Avids can be a real pain to get a good bleed on, so just keep trying and they should firm up.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to re-bleed them. Happened to me a few weeks back late at night before an Enduro the next morning. Bled them and they were good as new.

Comment: Make sure you pay plenty of attention to getting the last of the air out of the calliper too by pulling back on the string plunger and tapping the calliper with something light to dislodge bubbles. Do this with the lever held closed with a rubber band or cable tie. It's in the standard avid bleed instructions.

Comment: Good point. Lots of tapping, changing the angle of the lever and pinging the lever to remove all of the bubbles.